# После установки Bground пропала кнопка

Tags: java

Пропала кнопка после установки Bground. Лэйблы пропали тоже (При загрузке картинки из проекта `src\UI\Bground.jpg` пропадает только кнопка)
Догадываюсь что кнопка просто скрылась за картинкой которая инициализируется как Bground
Вот код:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Test {
    public static class HintTest extends JFrame {
        static JTextField input1 = new HintTextField("X1");
        static JTextField input2 = new HintTextField("X2");
        private JButton button = new JButton("Кнопка");


        HintTest() throws IOException {
            super("Test");
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            Container container = this.getContentPane();
            Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            setSize(dim.width / 2 - this.getSize().width / 2, dim.height / 2 - this.getSize().height / 2);
            setLocation(dim.width / 2 - this.getSize().width / 2, dim.height / 2 - this.getSize().height / 2);
            input1.setBounds(dim.width / 2 - this.getSize().width / 2 - 200, dim.height / 2 - 50 - this.getSize().height / 2 - 100, 100, 20);
            input2.setBounds(dim.width / 2 - this.getSize().width / 2 - 200, dim.height / 2 - this.getSize().height / 2 - 100, 100, 20);
            URL url = new URL("https://medialeaks.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/1465221347128633057-600x338.jpg");
            JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(url));
            add(background);
            setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(url)));
            ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(url);
            ii.getImage();
            container.add(input1);
            container.add(input2);
            container.add(button);
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(null);
            add(panel);
            setVisible(true);
            button.setBounds(dim.width / 2 - this.getSize().width / 2 - 200, dim.height / 2 - this.getSize().height / 2, 100, 40);
            button.addActionListener(new ButtonEventListener());
        }




        class ButtonEventListener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                HintTest.input1.setText("");
                HintTest.input2.setText("");
            }
        }

        static class HintTextField extends JTextField implements FocusListener {

            private final String hint;
            private boolean showingHint;


            private HintTextField(final String hint) {
                super(hint);
                this.hint = hint;
                this.showingHint = true;
                super.addFocusListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                if (this.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    super.setText("");
                    showingHint = false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                if (this.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    super.setText(hint);
                    showingHint = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public String getText() {
                return showingHint ? "" : super.getText();
            }

            public static class LayeredPaneDemo extends JPanel {
                private LayeredPaneDemo() {
                    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
                    layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 310));
                    Point origin = new Point(10, 20);
                    String[] layerStrings = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};
                    Color[] layerColors = {Color.red, Color.green, Color.blue};
                    for (int i = 0; i < layerStrings.length; i++) {
                        JLabel label = createColoredLabel(layerStrings[i], layerColors[i], origin);
                        layeredPane.add(label, new Integer(i));
                        origin.x += 35;
                        origin.y += 35;
                    }
                    add(layeredPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                }

                private JLabel createColoredLabel(String text, Color color, Point origin) {
                    JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
                    label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
                    label.setOpaque(true);
                    label.setBackground(color);
                    label.setForeground(Color.black);
                    label.setBounds(origin.x, origin.y, 140, 140);
                    return label;
                }

                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                        JFrame frame = new JFrame("LayeredPaneDemo");
                        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                        JComponent newContentPane = new LayeredPaneDemo();
                        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
                        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
                        frame.pack();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                        HintTest app = null;
                        try {
                            app = new HintTest();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        app.setVisible(true);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

При его запуске откроется два окна первое это моя программа с картинкой второе окно это возможный способ решения моей проблемы (наложение слоёв в java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал так:
1)Сделал загрузку через url
2)Указал что бы картинка была загружена в Temp
3)Сделал что бы после закрытия файл удалялся

```
package Test;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

class Test {

    static class HintTest extends JFrame {
        static JTextField input1 = new HintTextField("X1");
        static JTextField input2 = new HintTextField("X2");
        private JButton button = new JButton("Кнопка");


        HintTest() throws IOException {
            super("Test");
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            setSize(dim.width / 2 - this.getSize().width / 2, dim.height / 2 - this.getSize().height / 2);
            setLocation(dim.width / 2 - this.getSize().width / 2, dim.height / 2 - this.getSize().height / 2);
            input1.setBounds(dim.width / 2 - this.getSize().width / 2 - 200, dim.height / 2 - 50 - this.getSize().height / 2 - 100, 100, 20);
            input2.setBounds(dim.width / 2 - this.getSize().width / 2 - 200, dim.height / 2 - this.getSize().height / 2 - 100, 100, 20);
            URL url = new URL( "https://miro.medium.com/max/2836/1*ROagAxRi9uL-jeFLy5wQEQ.png" ); //указывается url к картинке
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
            String dir = System.getProperty("user.home");
            File f1 = new File(dir + "\\Appdata\\Local\\Temp\\Bground"); //указывается путь к файлу куда он будет сохранён
            ImageIO.write(image,"png",f1);
            ImageIO.write(image,"jpg",f1);
            Thread.onSpinWait();
            JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(dir + "\\Appdata\\Local\\Temp\\Bground"));
            add(background);
            setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(dir + "\\Appdata\\Local\\Temp\\Bground")));
            ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(dir + "\\Appdata\\Local\\Temp\\Bground");
            ii.getImage();
            final boolean delete = f1.delete();
            if(!delete) {
                f1.delete();
            }
            Container container = this.getContentPane();
            container.add(input1);
            container.add(input2);
            container.add(button);
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(null);
            add(panel);
            setVisible(true);
            button.setBounds(dim.width / 2 - this.getSize().width / 2 - 200, dim.height / 2 - this.getSize().height / 2, 100, 40);
            button.addActionListener(new ButtonEventListener());
            }
        }
    }


     class ButtonEventListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Test.HintTest.input1.setText("");
            Test.HintTest.input2.setText("");
        }
    }

    class HintTextField extends JTextField implements FocusListener {

        private final String hint;
        private boolean showingHint;


        HintTextField(final String hint) {
            super(hint);
            this.hint = hint;
            this.showingHint = true;
            super.addFocusListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            if (this.getText().isEmpty()) {
                super.setText("");
                showingHint = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            if (this.getText().isEmpty()) {
                super.setText(hint);
                showingHint = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String getText() {
            return showingHint ? "" : super.getText();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Test.HintTest app = null;
            try {
                app = new Test.HintTest();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            assert app != null;
            app.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```